# How to calculate the actual size of a table in apex oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a table "Photo_List" in the apex oracle, there are uploaded photos, how do I know the size of this table ?? Thank you for your help)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by size? Number of rows, number of bytes, something else?

Comment: number of bytes

Comment: I tried this time, but it didn't work "select segment_name bytes/1024/1024 MB
 from user_segments
 where segment_name='PHOTO_list';"

Comment: Tag properly!!!  If this is Oracle, why do I see SQL Server tag on your question?

Comment: Define “didn’t work”.  My guess is that you mean it returned no row In which case the first problem is that the name of the table in the data dictionary is probably in all upper case.  Assuming photos are stored in a BLOB column, the next issue is that the BLOBs are not part of the table segment, they’re part of a separate LOB segment.! Assuming you want to count the LOB segment with the table segment, you’d need to use the user_lobs table

Comment: I have a table and it has columns: Photo, Eid, description, I just want to know the size of this table

Comment: Not sure who, if anyone, you are replying to.  If `photo` is a `blob`, that data is technically not counted as part of the size of the table.  Is that what you want?  Or do you want to combine the size of the table segment with the size of the LOB segment?

Comment: I want to combine the segment size of the table with the segment size of a large object

Comment: The question "how big is a table" is a loaded question in Oracle. Some people want to know "how big is the *data stored in the table*", whereas other people want to know "how much *space on disk* has been reserved for this table". The data for the rows are stored in blocks, which usually have blank space (reserved room for future inserts/updates, or gaps from deleted rows); in turn the blocks are stored in segments which reserve disk space for the table. Plus, there is an overhead for metadata in each block.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how accurate you want the answer. The following will give you the size blob content. The rest of the row content is nominal in comparison.

```
select count(*) cnt
      ,apex_util.filesize_mask(sum(dbms_lob.getlength(image))) size 
from my_images;
```

Otherwise you're looking at queries on dictionary views
https://community.oracle.com/thread/1113909